# Need help reading rsync log. Problem checking cloned disk has the same files as original disk with rsync

Tags: rsync, cloning

I cloned a drive using **dd**. I stopped and resumed the process several times, so I want to make sure that all the files copied successfully.

I did some browsing with a file manager and the files seem to match up. I also ran **md5sum** on a few files and their md5 hashes match up. It looks like the dd cloning was successful, but I want to be completely sure. There are two many files and directories to manually check everything. I tried to verify the files correctly copied by doing a checksum check with **rsync**:

```
rsync -avrcn --log-file="/home/user_name/rsync-log.txt" /media/drive1 /media/drive2
```

However, rsync-log.txt just has multiple lines like this:

```
2021/09/27 21:21:12 [86457] cd+++++++++ documents/
2021/09/27 21:21:12 [86457] cd+++++++++ documents/spreadsheets/
2021/09/27 21:21:12 [86457] cd+++++++++ documents/spreadsheets/more-spreadsheets/
```

While the rsync log is too log to check manually, it looks like there are only directories listed and not individual files.

I'm not sure how to read this log file. I looked at **man rsync** under "--itemize-changes". If I'm reading that correctly, it looks like the log file is saying that these folders don't exist on drive2 (even though it looks like they do in file manager).

What is happening here? Am I reading the rsync log file incorrectly or did I use the wrong rsync command? As a side note, is there a good online reference for reading rsync log files with actual log file examples? Thanks.

Edit:
I think the solution posted by @roaima worked. Here is my entire new log file:

```
2021/09/30 19:35:41 [78771] building file list
2021/10/01 11:44:07 [78771] sent 86,960,331 bytes  received 87,516 bytes  1,498.07 bytes/sec
2021/10/01 11:44:07 [78771] total size is 2,984,736,671,932  speedup is 34,288.46 (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: I edited the example code's --log-file argument from "~/rsync-log.txt". @roaima correctly mentioned that rsync will not run with that. However, my rsync command did generate a log file, so I must have used an absolute file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it's telling you is that it wants to create all these directories (and probably the files they contain) on the destination. The reason it's telling you this is that `/media/drive2/drive1` and its contents doesn't exist, so it wants to create it.

You've missed a trailing `/` on the source path, so that `rsync` doesn't try to create that directory on the destination.

You'll have also had an error at the beginning of the process, something like

```
rsync: [client] failed to open log-file ~/rsync-log.txt: No such file or directory (2)
```

This is because `rsync` doesn't understand `~` and you should use `"$HOME"` instead. Or a relative path such as just the filename, `rsync-log.txt`

Try this,

```
rsync -avcn --log-file="$HOME/rsync-log.txt" /media/drive1/ /media/drive2
```